# nmapping two commands works only sometimes

Tags: key-bindings

Due to working in an environment with no clipboard support I have the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
nmap <F12> :set invnumber<CR> <bar> :set invpaste<CR>
```

Oddly enough, this works for some files I open, but any other file (or new ones) only the first part (`invnumber`) is run, and the `<bar>` and anything that follows is ignored.

- `nmap` shows the same output on working and non-working files
- I thought it might be somehow cached on a name, but new files with names matching working ones do not work either.
- I tried reversing the order of commands, but only the first is run on non-working files.
- Removed all plugins, but this behavior persists.
- Cleaned the vimrc except this line - persists.

What is the problem, or if it's not something simple, how do I debug this?

VIM version is 7.4, (I do not control this) and the plugins I use are matchit, surround, Tabular, and flake8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mapping is written badly: you don't need both `<CR>` and `<bar>` at the same time. Use either `:cmd1<bar>cmd2<CR>` or `:cmd1<CR>:cmd2<CR>`. Moreover, with `set` you can/should merge both settings into one command: `:set invnumber invpaste<CR>`.

Another thing you should take into account is that `number` is local to window, but `paste` is global. Therefore, they could not always match each other.

Comment: Also nnoremap should be used here